# Angular 2: if attr.title in html == array in component

Tags: html, arrays, if-statement, angular

```
<div class="kalender">
    <table *ngIf="datoer">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let cell of ukeEn()" 
                [attr.title]="cell.id">{{cell.text}}</td>
                </div>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I would like to check if `attr.title` (or `cell.id`) == `any of the element's .dato attribute` (an element is a type element called `Cell`, with the attribute `dato`) in an array called `datoer`, which is defined in my component. So I need to check the `attr.title` up against every value in the `datoer` array. Then I want to add an element (for ex. `div` or `p`) in the `td` if this condition is `true`.

Is this possible?
If you need more code samle to understand my problem, just ask.

Comment: Why don't you set the `title` attribute yourself? Why do you want to compare it to `cell.id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div class="kalender">
    <table *ngIf="datoer">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let cell of ukeEn()" [attr.title]="cell.id">
               <div *ngIf="datoerContains(cell)">{{cell.text}}</div>
            </td>            
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

In your component put this:

```
datoerContains(cell:any):boolean {
   for(let i = 0; i < this.datoer.length; i++) {
      if (this.datoer[i].dato == cell.dato) {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that the elements in 'datoer' is not in the format cell.id, but  Cell (a defined type with attribute id). So I need to check the array element's id attribute. How to write the component part then?

Comment: @MariusJ I have updated my answer. You can use ´datoerContains(cell:Cell)´. With ´any´ will work too.

Comment: Could you just edit the datoer[i].id to datoer[i].dato instead? I updated my question, using 'dato' attribute instead of 'id'.